# Get Value of closest class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some rows of table that contain data from each row. Every row has a button to be clicked. Is there any way to get JS know what button I click and get it value of clicked row?

My code so far in this fiddle:

```js
var rowNum = 0;
function addRow(frm) {
  rowNum++;
  var barang = $(this).closest("input.rf").find("input[name='rfdn']").val();
  var barangid = $(this).closest("input.rf").find("input[name='rfdid']").val();
  var price = $(this).closest("input.rf").find("input[name='rfdp']").val();;

  var row = '<tr id="rowNum' + rowNum + '">';
    row += '<td class="left"><input type="hidden" name="pitem[]" value="'+barangid+'" />'+barang+'</td>';
    row += '<td style="text-align:right;"><input type="number" min=0; name="qty[]" value="1" class="form-control" /></td>';
    row += '<td style="text-align:right;"><input type="hidden" name="price[]" value="'+price+'" />'+price+'</td>';
    row += '<td><a class="form-control btn btn-info btn-flat" onclick ="removeRow(' + rowNum + ')"><i class="fa fa-minus fa-fw"></i> Delete</a></td></tr>';
  jQuery('#refunds2').append(row);
}

function removeRow(rnum) {
  jQuery('#rowNum' + rnum).remove();
  rowNum--;
}
```

```css
.list {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding:10px;
}
.list td{
  padding:5px;
}
a.button, .list a.button {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    background: #003A88;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="list">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Product</td>
   <td>Refund</td>
      <td>Model</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>Unit Price</td>
      <td>Total</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Our Wedding</td>
   <td>
    <input type="hidden" class="rf" value="10745" id="rfdid" name="rfdid">
    <input type="hidden" class="rf" value="Our Wedding" id="rfdn" name="rfdn">
    <input type="hidden" class="rf" value="1" id="rfdq" name="rfdq">
    <input type="hidden" class="rf" value="60000.0000" id="rfdp" name="rfdp">
    <a class="button" onclick="addRow(this.form)">Refund</a>
    </td>
      <td>9786026100047</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Rp 60,000.00</td>
      <td>Rp 60,000.00</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Salihah Mom's Diary</td>
   <td>
    <input type="hidden" class="rf" value="13172" id="rfdid" name="rfdid">
    <input type="hidden" class="rf" value="Salihah Mom's Diary" id="rfdn" name="rfdn">
    <input type="hidden" class="rf" value="1" id="rfdq" name="rfdq">
    <input type="hidden" class="rf" value="66000.0000" id="rfdp" name="rfdp">
    <a class="button" onclick="addRow(this.form)">Refund</a>
   </td>
      <td>9786026114010</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Rp 66,000.00</td>
      <td>Rp 66,000.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>The Perfect Husband</td>
     <td>
          <input type="hidden" class="rf" value="6249" id="rfdid" name="rfdid">
          <input type="hidden" class="rf" value="The Perfect Husband" id="rfdn" name="rfdn">
          <input type="hidden" class="rf" value="1" id="rfdq" name="rfdq">
          <input type="hidden" class="rf" value="52195.0000" id="rfdp" name="rfdp">
          <a class="button" onclick="addRow(this.form)">Refund</a>
     </td>
        <td>9786026922311</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Rp 52,195.00</td>
        <td>Rp 52,195.00</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="totals">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="5">Sub-Total:</td>
        <td>Rp 178,195.00</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
                  
<table id="refunds2" class="list">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="left">Product</td>
      <td>Refund Qty</td>
      <td>Price</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>

</table>
```

My code result is still undefined from the closest row data. I want to get each data from each row when I click "Refund". So if I click first row, data I get is only the first row to append to another table.

Comment: If you log the ( this ) argument you can do a lot of things, like in 
addRow( elem ){ console.log( elem.parentNode.parentNode.children[0].innerText) }

Comment: But you have to call it via  addRow( this ) and not addRow( this.form )

Comment: @25r43q Hello, it get the tr.. not the input type hidden... How to get the input hidden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it this see working example: I just made an click event on the button and call the parent fiind element.

```js
var rowNum = 0;
$('.button').on('click',function() {
  rowNum++;
  var barang = $(this).parent().find("input[name='rfdn']").val();
  var barangid = $(this).parent().find("input[name='rfdid']").val();
  var price = $(this).parent().find("input[name='rfdp']").val();;

  var row = '<tr id="rowNum' + rowNum + '">';
    row += '<td class="left"><input type="hidden" name="pitem[]" value="'+barangid+'" />'+barang+'</td>';
    row += '<td style="text-align:right;"><input type="number" min=0; name="qty[]" value="1" class="form-control" /></td>';
    row += '<td style="text-align:right;"><input type="hidden" name="price[]" value="'+price+'" />'+price+'</td>';
    row += '<td><a class="form-control btn btn-info btn-flat" onclick ="removeRow(' + rowNum + ')"><i class="fa fa-minus fa-fw"></i> Delete</a></td></tr>';
  jQuery('#refunds2').append(row);
});

function removeRow(rnum) {
  jQuery('#rowNum' + rnum).remove();
  rowNum--;
}
```

```css
.list {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding:10px;
}
.list td{
  padding:5px;
}
a.button, .list a.button {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    background: #003A88;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="list">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Product</td>
   <td>Refund</td>
      <td>Model</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>Unit Price</td>
      <td>Total</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Our Wedding</td>
   <td>
    <input type="hidden" class="rf" value="10745" id="rfdid" name="rfdid">
    <input type="hidden" class="rf" value="Our Wedding" id="rfdn" name="rfdn">
    <input type="hidden" class="rf" value="1" id="rfdq" name="rfdq">
    <input type="hidden" class="rf" value="60000.0000" id="rfdp" name="rfdp">
    <a class="button">Refund</a>
    </td>
      <td>9786026100047</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Rp 60,000.00</td>
      <td>Rp 60,000.00</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Salihah Mom's Diary</td>
   <td>
    <input type="hidden" class="rf" value="13172" id="rfdid" name="rfdid">
    <input type="hidden" class="rf" value="Salihah Mom's Diary" id="rfdn" name="rfdn">
    <input type="hidden" class="rf" value="1" id="rfdq" name="rfdq">
    <input type="hidden" class="rf" value="66000.0000" id="rfdp" name="rfdp">
    <a class="button" >Refund</a>
   </td>
      <td>9786026114010</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Rp 66,000.00</td>
      <td>Rp 66,000.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>The Perfect Husband</td>
     <td>
          <input type="hidden" class="rf" value="6249" id="rfdid" name="rfdid">
          <input type="hidden" class="rf" value="The Perfect Husband" id="rfdn" name="rfdn">
          <input type="hidden" class="rf" value="1" id="rfdq" name="rfdq">
          <input type="hidden" class="rf" value="52195.0000" id="rfdp" name="rfdp">
          <a class="button">Refund</a>
     </td>
        <td>9786026922311</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Rp 52,195.00</td>
        <td>Rp 52,195.00</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="totals">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="5">Sub-Total:</td>
        <td>Rp 178,195.00</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
                  
<table id="refunds2" class="list">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="left">Product</td>
      <td>Refund Qty</td>
      <td>Price</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var rowNum = 0;
$(".button").click(function(){  
rowNum++;
  var barang = $(this).closest("td").find("input[name='rfdn']").val();
  var barangid = $(this).closest("td").find("input[name='rfdid']").val();
  var price = $(this).closest("td").find("input[name='rfdp']").val();
  var row = '<tr id="rowNum' + rowNum + '">';
    row += '<td class="left"><input type="hidden" name="pitem[]" value="'+barangid+'" />'+barang+'</td>';
    row += '<td style="text-align:right;"><input type="number" min=0; name="qty[]" value="1" class="form-control" /></td>';
    row += '<td style="text-align:right;"><input type="hidden" name="price[]" value="'+price+'" />'+price+'</td>';
    row += '<td><a class="form-control btn btn-info btn-flat" onclick ="removeRow(' + rowNum + ')"><i class="fa fa-minus fa-fw"></i> Delete</a></td></tr>';
  jQuery('#refunds2').append(row);

})
  

function removeRow(rnum) {
  jQuery('#rowNum' + rnum).remove();
  rowNum--;
}
```

```css
.list {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding:10px;
}
.list td{
  padding:5px;
}
a.button, .list a.button {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    background: #003A88;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="list">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Product</td>
   <td>Refund</td>
      <td>Model</td>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>Unit Price</td>
      <td>Total</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Our Wedding</td>
   <td>
    <input type="hidden" class="rf" value="10745" id="rfdid" name="rfdid">
    <input type="hidden" class="rf" value="Our Wedding" id="rfdn" name="rfdn">
    <input type="hidden" class="rf" value="1" id="rfdq" name="rfdq">
    <input type="hidden" class="rf" value="60000.0000" id="rfdp" name="rfdp">
    <a class="button">Refund</a>
    </td>
      <td>9786026100047</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Rp 60,000.00</td>
      <td>Rp 60,000.00</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Salihah Mom's Diary</td>
   <td>
    <input type="hidden" class="rf" value="13172" id="rfdid" name="rfdid">
    <input type="hidden" class="rf" value="Salihah Mom's Diary" id="rfdn" name="rfdn">
    <input type="hidden" class="rf" value="1" id="rfdq" name="rfdq">
    <input type="hidden" class="rf" value="66000.0000" id="rfdp" name="rfdp">
    <a class="button">Refund</a>
   </td>
      <td>9786026114010</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Rp 66,000.00</td>
      <td>Rp 66,000.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>The Perfect Husband</td>
     <td>
          <input type="hidden" class="rf" value="6249" id="rfdid" name="rfdid">
          <input type="hidden" class="rf" value="The Perfect Husband" id="rfdn" name="rfdn">
          <input type="hidden" class="rf" value="1" id="rfdq" name="rfdq">
          <input type="hidden" class="rf" value="52195.0000" id="rfdp" name="rfdp">
          <a class="button">Refund</a>
     </td>
        <td>9786026922311</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Rp 52,195.00</td>
        <td>Rp 52,195.00</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="totals">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="5">Sub-Total:</td>
        <td>Rp 178,195.00</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
                  
<table id="refunds2" class="list">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="left">Product</td>
      <td>Refund Qty</td>
      <td>Price</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you try to edit "closest("input.rf")" to "closest("tr")". i think you are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use (this) keyword to select the clicked button ,used closest method to select parent tr and use attr method to add attribute

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("a.button").on('click',function(){
 $(this).attr('class',$(this).closest("tr").attr("id"));
 });
 });
```

Edit
You use anchor tag as a button here you have to use these functions preventDefault() and stopPropagation();

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("a.button").on('click',function(event){
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
 $(this).attr('class',$(this).closest("tr").attr("id"));
 });
  });
```